# Layout behavior of absolute positioning with appropriate scroll behavior

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create tooltips for items in a scrollable list.  I would like the tooltips to:

- be seen outside (not clipped by) the scroll area
- appear immediately after the item they are a tooltip for
- be removed from the content of the containing item

[image: desired result]

The markup looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='option'>Option</div>
    <div class='tooltip'><h4>Tooltip</h4> Tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip.</div>
  </li>
  <!-- plus fourteen more identical li's -->
</ul>
```

with css like this:

```
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  border:thin solid gray;
  width:80px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.tooltip {
  display:none;
  border:thin solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
  background-color:white;
  z-index:10000;
  padding:3px;
  width:150px;
  position:absolute;
}

.option:hover + .tooltip{
  display:block;
}
```

Here is a demo of what I have found: http://plnkr.co/edit/vhKquqeswyDwvDQNP12G?p=preview

If I use relative positioning on the tooltip,  it appears in the correct location but is clipped by the scroll area (and it is not removed from the content of the li).

[image]

If I use absolute positioning, the tooltip displays outside the scroll area (desired), but appears in the wrong place once the ul has been scrolled away from the top.

[image: misplaced tool tip]

If I use absolute positioning and apply a relatively positioned wrapper to fix the tooltip to the position of the list item, the tooltip is in the right position even after scrolling and is removed from the content of the list item, but is clipped by the list area.

[image: with relative wrapper]

Is there anyway to achieve all three things that I want using css?

Comment: Your second example (absolute positioning) seems to be working in Firefox, but breaks in Chrome as you described.

Comment: @MarcAudet Good catch, thanks!  IE exhibits the same behavior as Chrome.  I wonder what the correct behavior is.

Comment: I have run across this issue before related to absolute positioning, I can't remember if I saw a fix for it.  Opera and Safari also show the same behavior.

Comment: I tried containing the tooltip inside the parent div, but same issue. You may have to resort to JS.

Comment: How would you do it with js? Mouse over event shows tooltip div with fixed position?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what you're trying for, but thinking outside the box the following could give the user an interesting UX experience...

Note this may not work on mobile devices as it relies on hover, not touch. You will need to test and fix events / add js shims where needed.

### Demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYkyjbS9vPzQ4EYXKHHG?p=preview

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<h3>Relative positioning</h3>  
  <div class='wrapper'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class='option'>Option</div>
          <div class='tooltip'><h4>Tooltip 1</h4> Tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip.</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class='option'>Option</div>
          <div class='tooltip'><h4>Tooltip 2</h4> Tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip.</div>
        </li>
        ... etc
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
body{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:80%;
  }

ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  border:thin solid gray;
  width:5em;
  height:10em;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.tooltip {
  display:none;
  border:thin solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
  background-color:white;
  padding:3px;
  width:150px;
}

.option:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.option:hover + .tooltip{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:6em;
}

.wrapper{position:relative;}
```

Further work: if you change the styling so the tooltip text is on the left, and has a thick border the same colour as the highlight colour of the option it could look quite nice!

http://plnkr.co/edit/7JTjgxDTjSNonIZCOPZE?p=preview

Further work required to make this accessible (longdesc or aria-describedby anyone?)